# "The method 'where' was called on null." when using streambuilder with firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm using StreamBuilder to stream some data from Firestore.

It's working good and the data is appearing but there's an error in the console.

That's the code that I think it may contains the error:

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Consumer<AppState>(
                    builder: (context, appState, _) =>
                        StreamBuilder<List<Dentist>>(
                      stream: database.dentistsStream(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) => Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          for (final dentist in snapshot.data.where((e) => e
                              .categoryIds
                              .contains(appState.selectedCategoryId)))
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: DentistItem(
                                dentist: dentist,
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

and the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4oEh.jpg)

Any help?!

Note: I know that 'for' here is not supported in the old versions of Dart.

Comment: Note: I know that 'for' here is not supported in the OLD versions of Dart. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before create your column from your snapshot, be sure that your snapshot has data, `if (snapshot.hasData)`;

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
  child: Consumer<AppState>(
    builder: (context, appState, _) => StreamBuilder<List<Dentist>>(
      stream: database.dentistsStream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData)
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              for (final dentist in snapshot.data.where((e) =>
                  e.categoryIds.contains(appState.selectedCategoryId)))
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: DentistItem(
                    dentist: dentist,
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          );
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```